# get 10 comments for each answer by one query

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

i have a comments table, like this:
`id`, `answer_id`, `content`

now i want to get latest 10 comments for EACH answer id.
list of answer ids are provided like (1,5,11,27,82)

is it possible to get all related comments by just one query ?

i currently do this by php's foreach:

```
foreach ($answers as $answer) { // query mysql for its comments
```

Comment: If you want the "latest" comments, you're going to need a temporal column, right? Or do you have some other way in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer helpful "[Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12117654/4465711)", and you should refer to it for an explanation of the query shown below.

[DB-Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e4beadfa40a2e481d8626aebd9aa8259)

```
create table comments (
    id int not null, 
    answer_id int not null, 
    content varchar(100),
    dt datetime);
```

Populate with some data:

```
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (1,1,'numerable','2016-09-24 22:55:55'),(2,1,'reviver','2016-09-21 10:27:20'),(3,1,'statutory','2016-09-25 12:27:06'),(4,1,'lithograph','2016-09-23 14:35:29'),(5,1,'optima','2016-09-21 21:53:24'),(6,1,'rationales','2016-09-24 23:52:35'),(7,1,'directly','2016-09-27 15:51:09'),(8,1,'astounding','2016-09-22 08:44:40'),(9,1,'abut','2016-09-26 21:01:11'),(10,1,'synchronously','2016-09-24 19:53:08'),(11,1,'Dante','2016-09-26 16:10:29'),(12,1,'handcuff','2016-09-24 15:05:00'),(13,1,'apparition','2016-09-25 02:56:07'),(14,1,'vents','2016-09-27 18:17:58'),(15,1,'unduly','2016-09-22 14:14:24'),(16,1,'Swarthmore','2016-09-22 01:48:27'),(17,1,'expanding','2016-09-21 11:42:46'),(18,1,'shapelessness','2016-09-27 14:59:50'),(19,1,'differentiations','2016-09-24 04:14:17'),(20,1,'Geminid','2016-09-22 01:10:45');

INSERT INTO comments VALUES (21,5,'coordinators','2017-01-03 23:10:11'),(22,5,'fiftieth','2017-01-01 12:46:11'),(23,5,'heaving','2017-01-11 18:57:39'),(24,5,'computer','2017-01-11 20:28:05'),(25,5,'instill','2017-01-07 18:23:06'),(26,5,'Steiner','2017-01-03 05:00:50'),(27,5,'decompression','2017-01-06 13:05:00'),(28,5,'rainstorm','2017-01-03 11:16:04'),(29,5,'gossiped','2017-01-08 22:02:20'),(30,5,'fledged','2017-01-01 19:32:23'),(31,5,'overlapping','2017-01-06 19:36:01'),(32,5,'orations','2017-01-06 00:04:57'),(33,5,'interprocess','2017-01-04 11:33:25'),(34,5,'investigates','2017-01-10 12:54:02'),(35,5,'hamlet','2017-01-02 11:58:37'),(36,5,'clapping','2017-01-06 17:21:52'),(37,5,'breakpoints','2017-01-08 03:03:55'),(38,5,'caviar','2017-01-07 03:24:26'),(39,5,'searched','2017-01-07 03:05:39'),(40,5,'unselfishly','2017-01-07 15:34:07');
```

Suggested query:

```
SELECT id, answer_id, content, dt
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        answer_id,
        content,
        dt,
    @rn := IF(@prev = answer_id, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
    @prev := answer_id
    FROM comments
    JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
    ORDER BY answer_id, dt DESC
) AS T1
WHERE rn <= 10 AND answer_id IN (1,5);
```

Results:

```
id    answer_id    content        dt
14    1            vents          2016-09-27 18:17:58
 7    1            directly       2016-09-27 15:51:09
18    1            shapelessness  2016-09-27 14:59:50
 9    1            abut           2016-09-26 21:01:11
11    1            Dante          2016-09-26 16:10:29
 3    1            statutory      2016-09-25 12:27:06
13    1            apparition     2016-09-25 02:56:07
 6    1            rationales     2016-09-24 23:52:35
 1    1            numerable      2016-09-24 22:55:55
10    1            synchronously  2016-09-24 19:53:08
24    5            computer       2017-01-11 20:28:05
23    5            heaving        2017-01-11 18:57:39
34    5            investigates   2017-01-10 12:54:02
29    5            gossiped       2017-01-08 22:02:20
37    5            breakpoints    2017-01-08 03:03:55
25    5            instill        2017-01-07 18:23:06
40    5            unselfishly    2017-01-07 15:34:07
38    5            caviar         2017-01-07 03:24:26
39    5            searched       2017-01-07 03:05:39
31    5            overlapping    2017-01-06 19:36:01
```

Comment: @MehdiAzmoudeh I don't know which is faster; sorry. And, yes, it is complicated -- even to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a query with multiple SELECTs and combine the result with [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE answer_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 
UNION
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE answer_id = 5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
UNION
-- … and so on for 11, 27, 82
;
```

This sorts the query for each `answer_id` by `id` in descending order and gets the first 10 rows of the result, i.e. the last 10 rows for this `answer_id`.